# problem to play a video with parole

Tags: video-player

I've a problem using [parole](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/parole/) in my **xubuntu14.04**. When I try **to play a video MP4 or OGG using parole** I get this error message: **"GStreamer backend error: Could not initialize supporting library "** Can anyone help me to find out the solution?

@AB here is the output:

```
    user@mail:~/Downloads/ices-0.4$ apt-cache policy parole
parole:
  Installed: 0.6.1-0ubuntu3
  Candidate: 0.6.1-0ubuntu3.1
  Version table:
     0.6.1-0ubuntu3.1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages
 *** 0.6.1-0ubuntu3 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
user@mail:~/Downloads/ices-0.4$
```

Thanks:D

Comment: What exactly are you doing? What Ubuntu release? Are you trying to play a file, a DVD? Can you please provide more information, consider EDIT your question.

Comment: What is "video with parole"?

Comment: @Pilot6 https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/parole/ or here https://launchpad.net/~xubuntu-dev/+archive/ubuntu/xfce-4.12

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy parole`